# Moving data between listbox which binded to different datasources in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with many listbox that listing all image from a folder which binded into different datasources and i have no idea how to move data between each other. it looks like this

```
Private Sub LoadISrcFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoadISrcFolderToolStripMenuItem.Click
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK And FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder1Path.Text Or FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder2Path.Text Or FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder3Path.Text Then
            MsgBox("Unable to open a same folder")
        Else
            SourceFolderPath.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
            Dim filextension = {"*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif"}
            Dim filelist As New List(Of FileInfo)
            Dim directory As New DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)

            For Each filetypes In filextension
                filelist.AddRange(directory.GetFiles(filetypes))
            Next

            filelist.Sort(Function(file1, file2) file1.Name.CompareTo(file2.Name))

            With ListBox1
                .DisplayMember = NameOf(FileInfo.Name)
                .ValueMember = NameOf(FileInfo.FullName)
                .DataSource = filelist
            End With
        End If
End Sub
```

and the other listbox looks like this

```
Private Sub AddFolder1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddFolder1.Click
        If TargetFolderBrowser1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK And TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath = SourceFolderPath.Text Or TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath = Folder2Path.Text Or TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath = Folder3Path.Text Then
            MsgBox("Unable to open a same folder")
        Else
            Folder1Path.Enabled = True
            ListFolder1.Enabled = True
            ListFolder1.Items.Clear()

            Folder1Path.Text = TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath
            Dim filextension = {"*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif"}
            Dim filelist As New List(Of FileInfo)
            Dim directory As New DirectoryInfo(TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath)

            For Each filetypes In filextension
                filelist.AddRange(directory.GetFiles(filetypes))
            Next

            filelist.Sort(Function(file1, file2) file1.Name.CompareTo(file2.Name))

            With Listfolder1
                .DisplayMember = NameOf(FileInfo.Name)
                .ValueMember = NameOf(FileInfo.FullName)
                .DataSource = filelist
            End With

            AddFolder1.Visible = False
            RemoveFolder1.Visible = True
            TargetFolder1.Text = Path.GetFileName(TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath)

            'if the character length is more than 18 character then trim it
            If Path.GetFileName(TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath).Length > 18 Then
                MoveImageToTarget1.Text = "Move Selected Image to " & Mid(Path.GetFileName(TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath), 1, 16) & ".."
            Else
                MoveImageToTarget1.Text = "Move Selected Image to " & Path.GetFileName(TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath) & ""
            End If

            If ListFolder1.Items.Count > 0 Then
                StatusLabel.Text = "Folder '" & Path.GetFileName(TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath) & "' successfully loaded, there's " & ListFolder1.Items.Count & " files in it."
                RemoveFromList.Enabled = True
            Else
                StatusLabel.Text = "Folder '" & Path.GetFileName(TargetFolderBrowser1.SelectedPath) & "' successfully loaded, there's no file in it"
            End If

            If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
                MoveImageToTarget1.Enabled = True
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

Before of that, i use this code to list all files from the folder but it can't filter the images files. I'm moving the data by deleting the record from one listbox and create the same value in another listbox.

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK And FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder1Path.Text Or FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder2Path.Text Or FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Folder3Path.Text Then
            MsgBox("Unable to open a same folder")
        Else
            SourceFolderPath.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
            Dim filenames As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
            If filenames.Length > 0 Then
                For Each names As String In filenames
                    Dim justname As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(names)
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(justname)
                Next
            End If
        End If
```

Is there any idea how to move data between listbox with different datasources, or how i can create and delete data in the datasources and update the listboxes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When a control is bound to a data source and you want to make changes, you change the data source. That's it, that's all. If you have `ListBoxes` bound to generic `List` objects, the `ListBoxes` are irrelevant. I would hope that you already know how to add and remove items in a `List(Of T)` and that's all you have to do here. If you have two `List(Of FileInfo)` and you want to move an item from one to the other, you get an item from the first list, remove the item from that list and then add it to the second. That's how it works in the "real world" and that's how it works in programming.

The extra step here is that, if those `List` objects are bound to your controls, changes you make to them will not be reflected in those controls. That's because the `List(Of T)` class doesn't raise any events when those changes occur, so there's nothing to notify the control to update. There are two options to address this.

Firstly, you might use a `BindingList(Of T)` instead of a `List(Of T)`. The former is created for the purposes of data binding so it does raise appropriate events when changes occur. Just be aware that it also lacks some functionality that `List(Of T)` has, e.g. a `Sort` method.

Secondly, you can use a `BindingSource`. Instead of binding your list directly to the control, you can bind the list to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the control. Then, when you make a change, you can call an appropriate method on the `BindingSource` to raise an event so the control updates. You should call `ResetCurrentItem` or `ResetItem` to update a single item if possible but, if that is not enough to sufficiently update the control, call `ResetBindings` to update everything. Removing an item may require the latter, although I haven't tested specifically.

One thing I forgot to say previously was that, if you're moving items from one list to the other, you're going to need to get the items to move in the first place. If you're using a `BindingSource` and selecting one item at a time, you can use the `Current` property of the `BindingSource` to get that item. You can also use the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` or, if you've enabled multiselect, the `SelectedItems` property. In each case, you'll be getting `Object` references, so you'll need to cast as the actual type, which is `FileInfo` in this case.